# sudo checkinstall - installation failed

Tags: ffmpeg, makefile, raspberry-pi, debian, raspbian

I'm trying to install ffmpeg on Raspbian by following these steps :

```
 cd ffmpeg
./configure --prefix=/usr
time make -j 8
cat RELEASE
sudo checkinstall
```

but when I do the sudo checkinstall step, it gave me an error :

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/ffmpeg $ sudo checkinstall -y

checkinstall 1.6.2, Copyright 2009 Felipe Eduardo Sanchez Diaz Duran
           This software is released under the GNU GPL.



*****************************************
**** Debian package creation selected ***
*****************************************

This package will be built according to these values:

0 -  Maintainer: [ root@raspberrypi ]
1 -  Summary: [ Package created with checkinstall 1.6.2 ]
2 -  Name:    [ ffmpeg ]
3 -  Version: [  ]
4 -  Release: [ 1 ]
5 -  License: [ GPL ]
6 -  Group:   [ checkinstall ]
7 -  Architecture: [ armhf ]
8 -  Source location: [ ffmpeg ]
9 -  Alternate source location: [  ]
10 - Requires: [  ]
11 - Provides: [ ffmpeg ]
12 - Conflicts: [  ]
13 - Replaces: [  ]

Enter a number to change any of them or press ENTER to continue:

Installing with make install...

========================= Installation results ===========================
INSTALL doc/ffmpeg.1
INSTALL doc/ffprobe.1
INSTALL doc/ffserver.1
INSTALL doc/ffmpeg-all.1
INSTALL doc/ffprobe-all.1
INSTALL doc/ffserver-all.1
INSTALL doc/ffmpeg-utils.1
INSTALL doc/ffmpeg-scaler.1
INSTALL doc/ffmpeg-resampler.1
INSTALL doc/ffmpeg-codecs.1
INSTALL doc/ffmpeg-bitstream-filters.1
INSTALL doc/ffmpeg-formats.1
INSTALL doc/ffmpeg-protocols.1
INSTALL doc/ffmpeg-devices.1
INSTALL doc/ffmpeg-filters.1
INSTALL doc/libavutil.3
INSTALL doc/libswscale.3
INSTALL doc/libswresample.3
INSTALL doc/libavcodec.3
INSTALL doc/libavformat.3
INSTALL doc/libavdevice.3
INSTALL doc/libavfilter.3
INSTALL doc/ffmpeg.1
INSTALL doc/ffprobe.1
INSTALL doc/ffserver.1
INSTALL doc/ffmpeg-all.1
INSTALL doc/ffprobe-all.1
INSTALL doc/ffserver-all.1
INSTALL doc/ffmpeg-utils.1
INSTALL doc/ffmpeg-scaler.1
INSTALL doc/ffmpeg-resampler.1
INSTALL doc/ffmpeg-codecs.1
INSTALL doc/ffmpeg-bitstream-filters.1
INSTALL doc/ffmpeg-formats.1
INSTALL doc/ffmpeg-protocols.1
INSTALL doc/ffmpeg-devices.1
INSTALL doc/ffmpeg-filters.1
INSTALL doc/libavutil.3
INSTALL doc/libswscale.3
INSTALL doc/libswresample.3
INSTALL doc/libavcodec.3
INSTALL doc/libavformat.3
INSTALL doc/libavdevice.3
INSTALL doc/libavfilter.3
INSTALL install-progs-yes
INSTALL ffmpeg
INSTALL ffprobe
INSTALL ffserver
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/share/ffmpeg’: No such file or directory
Makefile:161: recipe for target 'install-data' failed
make: *** [install-data] Error 1

****  Installation failed. Aborting package creation.

Cleaning up...OK

Bye.
```

Can anyone help me ? What can I do ? I'm not gonna lie, I'm a noob and I don't really know where to start, I tried 3-4 things but it didn't work.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, I created the folder manually:

`sudo mkdir /usr/share/ffmpeg` than `sudo checkinstall` again.

Answer (score 1):

actually your meant to add your version number when it asks which you can find by doing

`cat RELEASE`

and but before you must do make the directory

`sudo mkdir /usr/share/ffmpeg`